# How to moderate (manually approve) comments of a specific (registered) User

Tags: comments, moderation

I have a WordPress blog that gets a ton of comments. I have a freelancer that does support on the blog and replies to these comments. In a tryout phase, though, I'd like the comments of this support person to be manually approved by me.

How could this be done? Hold comments of a specific user in the moderation queue until approved?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with coding, you could try a custom filter based on the WP_Comment object.  Perhaps something like the following:

```
function wpse_wp_insert_comment($id, $comment) {    
        // Add your user_id, or use email address instead.
        if ( empty($comment->comment_author ) || $comment->user_id!== 1 )
            wp_set_comment_status( $comment, 'hold' );
}
add_action('wp_insert_comment', 'wpse_wp_insert_comment', 10, 2);
```

-Or ...

```
// Same method, but using userdata to compare email address instead
function wpse_wp_insert_comment($id, $comment) {    
    $author = empty($comment->comment_author) ? NULL : get_userdata($comment->user_id);
    // Be sure to update this line with YOUR actual email address.
    if ( empty($comment->comment_author ) || $author->user_email!=="you@your-domain.com" )
        wp_set_comment_status( $comment, 'hold' );
}
add_action('wp_insert_comment', 'wpse_wp_insert_comment', 10, 2);
```

Extrapolated from a Tom Mcfarlin article "[Programmatically Mark a Comment as Unapproved](https://tommcfarlin.com/mark-a-comment-as-unapproved/)".  See the "Gotcha" warning he throws out regarding users' anticipated outcome vs actual manipulated results caused by this type of function.